# externally-loaded images sizes for 4S full-size of screen

Tags: ios, ios7

Sorry if this seems like a naive quesiton but I'm having a hard time finding a definitive solution to this.

I have an app that is loading external images that are to be the full size of the screen (ie not local, not @2x question).

I was expecting it to be 640 x 960 / 72ppi for 4s images and 640 x 1136 / 72ppi for 5 / 5s. So we cut up a few test images and loaded them in but they were all 2x too big. When we cut images down to 320 x 480 / 72ppi for 4s, everything worked fine.  Is this the expected behavior? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize the image and display it?
`[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:loadedData]` and `UIImageView`?
If so, try:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:loadedData scale:2.0]
```

Image with 640x960 pixels without scale(1.0 default) is 2x too big; This is expected behavior. You know that is **retina**(i.e. @2x) image, you should specify explicit `scale`.